# How do I write a program that shows the multiples of a number?

Tags: javascript

I have this function called "Multiples" using function declaration notation with the following parameters & return value:

Parameters:

1. numVal: a whole number
2. M=multiples: a whole number

Return value: A string that contains all the multiples of the numVal argument from 1 to multiples.

The below code is what I have written (it does not work).

```
var showMultiples =function(num, numMultiples){
    var i;     
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= numMultiples ; i++)
    {
      result = num * i "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

console.log('showMultiples(2,8) returns: ' + showMultiples(2,8));
console.log('showMultiples(3,2) returns: ' + showMultiples(3,2));
console.log('showMultiples(5,4) returns: ' + showMultiples(5,4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `result` in every step of the for loop. Instead add to the existing var. Also you need to concatenate your number and your string. By the way "does not work" is a bad error description.

```
result += num * i + "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a declaration of the variable `result` and initialize with an empty string. Then spend some parenthesis and a plus sign for the result.

```
result += (num * i) + "\n";
```

```js
var showMultiples = function(num, numMultiples) {
        var i,
            result = '';
        for (i = 1; i <= numMultiples; i++) {
            result += (num * i) + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    };

console.log('showMultiples(2,8) returns: ' + showMultiples(2, 8));
console.log('showMultiples(3,2) returns: ' + showMultiples(3, 2));
console.log('showMultiples(5,4) returns: ' + showMultiples(5, 4));
```